# apt-get -f install "error"

Tags: apt

```
:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin locales
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 520 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,071 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 76346 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.24-17_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.24-17_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive `interest-await'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.24-17_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The problem is as it is

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, maybe due to usage of PPA, or cross package, or a bug this libc package, the tigger directive is not understood by your system. Remove the trigger may fix the issue, then continue the normal upgrade.

```
sudo -s
echo "#Nothing to do here" > /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.triggers
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: The problem is as it is

Comment: Can you do a `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.triggers` and provide the file content?

Comment: Just updated my process as the echo probably returned a permission denied.